# Computed property isn't recomputed when array dependency is mutated

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using a computed property as the `items` for a `dom-repeat`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{double(values)}}">
  <span>{{item}}</span>
</template>
```

When its dependency `values` changes, the property isn't recomputed.

```
addValue: function() {
  this.push('values', this.values.length+1);
  this.async(this.addValue, 1000);
},
```

If, instead of mutating `values`, I set it to a new array, it does work:

```
this.set('values', this.values.concat(this.values.length+1))
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/SmAHKMHhSPWgmBhBBzAv?p=preview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spoke with Scott Miles, a member of the team behind Polymer, and I got this back:

In order for the computed property to bind properly, you must use `[[double(values.*)]]`.

The parameter passed to your `double` function will be an object with properties `path`, `value`, and `base`, just as in path observation.

- `path` will refer to a path string that specifies if `length` or `splices` was updated in the array,
- `value` will be the value of `length` or `splices`, and
- `base` will refer to your array.

Example:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[double(values.*)]]">
  <span>[[item]]</span>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  double: function(e) {
    return e.base.map(function(n) { return n*2; });
  }
```

Docs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Idrz5XvLn9SZ35iR8pGT?p=preview

A `dom-repeat` template expects to be working with a collection, and thus when you bind it to `values` directly, it knows to keep tabs on the items in `values`.

Computed properties do not have any such expectations, and so `[[double(values)]]` doesn't work in this case because it will only update when the `values` reference itself changes, **not** when the items in the array change. Using `values.*` lets Polymer know that it should update the computed property binding when the array's contents are mutated.

---

I wouldn't post this here in Scott's stead if not for

> sjmiles: @vartan: otoh, if you could transcribe what you learned, it would help me, time is my least elastic resource

Comment: Also notice that the computed property's function isn't passed the array the directly anymore, but as a property named `base`. So `function(values) {...}` becomes `function(info) {var values = info.base; ...}`

Comment: @TrevorDixon Goodness, I neglected to mention that! Big whoops. I added all the extra detail in :) Thanks for noticing!